# A number from 1 to 1000 is selected. What is P(The Last Two Digits of the Cube = 1)?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

Y.A. Rozanov. Probability Theory: A Concise Course Chapter 1 Problem 9.

A number from 1 to 1000 is selected at random. What is probability that the last two digits of  it's cube are equal to 1?

The book reports that the  answer is .01.

I believe the  answer follows from the fact that number $100x^2+10y+z$ cubed has the form $(100x^2+10y+z)^3$ = A trinomial expansion and using this knowledge to somehow show that there are only two solutions and each is 1/10 likely.

Comment: What prevents you from carrying out your ideas? Note that you can "throw away" many of the terms in the expansion because they are divisible by 100. (You are working mod 100.)

Comment: 1. Consider how you can get the unit digit to be one after the cube(All numbers **will have** unit digit as `1`). 2. Remove those which can't generate `11` after cube.

Comment: @Potato I know. I think I'm just tired and frustrated. I think the only term that can contribute is the z^3 because the 30y^2z +30z^2y terms are too large. I know this should be easy.

Comment: @BackinaFlash z must be 1 I suppose. Then ....

Comment: It should be $100 x + 10 y + z$, not $100 x^2 + 10 y + z$.  But the $x$ doesn't matter. The only terms that are not necessarily divisible by $100$ are $30 y z^2 + z^3$.  So what must $z$ be, and what must $y$ be?

Comment: @student http://codepad.org/bF4HCOTo =)

Comment: I hope you'll see the logic?

Comment: @Robert Israel I now see that the answer is z=1 and y=7.

Comment: @BackinaFlash Yes. But now I am questioning my logic. I argued that the answer is .01 because 7 and 1 can each be taken 1 way out of 10 possibilities. If you where simply guessing digits you would have a 1/100 chance of guessing 7 and 1. But now I think it would be better to have said that there are only 10 possibilities out of 1000 because there are only 10 ways to end the digit with "71". I like that argument more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that the number is $n=100a+10b+c$, where $a,b$, and $c$ are decimal digits. Let $m=10a+b$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
n^3&=(10m+c)^3\\
&=1000m^3+300m^2c+30mc^2+c^3\\
&=100\left(10m^3+3m^2c\right)+30mc^2+c^3\;.
\end{align*}$$

The first term in the last line clearly has no effect on the last two digits of $n^3$, and the second has no effect on the last digit. The last digit of $n^3$ is the last digit of $c^3$, which is $1$ if and only if $c=1$. You’d pretty much arrived at this point on your own.

In that case the second-last digit of $n^3$ is the second-last digit of $30mc^2$, which is the last digit of $3m$, and that’s the last digit of $3b$. When is the last digit of $3b$ equal to $1$?

Comment: b=7. So the only solution that gives the correct answer is b=7 and c=1. And each of those numbers is taken from 10 possible digits and are taken independently, so the probability is (1/10)(1/10). Thank You Again.

Comment: @student: You’re welcome. Yes, $b=7$ is the only possibility, so you get $10$ such numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The number $3$ has no common divisors with $\phi(100)=|\mathbb{Z}_{100}^*|=40$, so cubing is a permutation of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{100}^*$. If a number has common divisor with $100$ its cube ain't gonna end with two ones.

No need to work out the possibilities for $n$ :-)

The upshot here is that this argument goes through unchanged, if we replace the pair of digits $11$ with any other pair such that the latte digit is one of $1,3,7,9$. Hence the probability is $1/100$ for all such pairs.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm not following the notation either. I am curious though.

Comment: What theorem is this?

Comment: @student: Consider the numbers from 1 to 100. Throw away those that are divisible by either 2 or 5. Forty numbers remain. My hint depends on a little bit of group theory. In an abelian group of order 40, raising the elements to third power will permute the elements. Meaning that exactly one of those forty numbers has a cube that ends with 11. Exactly the same thing will happen once in each century.

Comment: The result being used is that because $\gcd(3,40)=1$, the homomorphism $f:A\to A, x\mapsto x^3$ from a finite abelian group $A$ to itself has a trivial kernel. Therefore the freshman theorem implies that the image of $f$ has 40 elements. Therefore it is a bijection.

Comment: I can't follow this argument. It is too advanced. Thanks. I want to study group theory some day. Is there a good book on it you could recommend?

Comment: @student: This much will be covered in any first course in abstract algebra. There are plenty of good books, and sets of lecture notes. It may be best to ask someone at your department for they can tell which book they will be using in your future course.